# Add parent div to button group where there is span

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have a set of button and span inside a div, i am trying to add a parent div to each group of button.

**HTML :**

```
<div class="btnWrapper">
<button type="button" class="fr-bttn" title="Bold">One</button>
<button type="button" class="fr-bttn" title="Italic">Two</button>
<button type="button" class="fr-bttn" title="Underline">three</button>
<button type="button" class="fr-bttn" title="Bold">Four</button>
<span class="sptr"><span>
<button type="button" class="fr-bttn" title="Strike">five</button>
<button type="button" class="fr-bttn" title="color">Six</button>
<span class="sptr"><span>
<button type="button" class="fr-bttn" title="Strike">Seven</button>
<button type="button" class="fr-bttn" title="color">Eight</button>
<button type="button" class="fr-bttn" title="color">Nine</button>
</div>
```

I would like to achieve something like this

```
<div class="btnWrapper">
 <div class="parent_01">
    <button type="button" class="fr-bttn" title="Bold">One</button>
    <button type="button" class="fr-bttn" title="Italic">Two</button>
    <button type="button" class="fr-bttn" title="Underline">three</button>
    <button type="button" class="fr-bttn" title="Bold">Four</button>
  <div>   
 <span class="sptr"><span>
 <div class="parent_02">
    <button type="button" class="fr-bttn" title="Strike">five</button>
    <button type="button" class="fr-bttn" title="color">Six</button>
 </div>
<span class="sptr"><span>
<div class="parent_03">
    <button type="button" class="fr-bttn" title="Strike">Seven</button>
    <button type="button" class="fr-bttn" title="color">Eight</button>
    <button type="button" class="fr-bttn" title="color">Nine</button>
 </div>
</div>
```

Edit: 
i tried
JavaScript

```
$(".fr-bttn").slice(0,3).wrapAll("<div class='parent1'></div>")
```

But the problem am facing is that html is will generated dynamically, i cant set each by using slice(), i need to do something with `<span></span>` ?

Comment: and what is stopping you? sorry, I'm sure there must be something else in your question, but I'm missing it

Comment: Did you try jquery next()? http://api.jquery.com/next/

Comment: [nextUntil](http://api.jquery.com/nextuntil/) might be a better fit

Comment: @Fabio: Updated my question, pls check

Comment: my vote for nextUntil. @mplungjan you'd add this as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at this

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/c0jefv9m/)

```
var $span = $('.btnWrapper').find("span");
$span.each(function(i) { // what is near the spans
    var $div = $('<div class="parent_0'+i+'">Hello '+i+'</div>');
    var $content =  Array.prototype.slice.call($(this).prevUntil("div,span")).reverse();
    $div.append($content);
    $('.btnWrapper').append($div).append($(this));
});
// handle the rest
var $div = $('<div class="parent_0'+$span.length+'">Hello'+$span.length+'</div>');
$('.btnWrapper > button').appendTo($div);
$('.btnWrapper').append($div);
```